# Can I utilitze the GoogleGlass Compass or would i need to remake it for my needs?

Tags: android, google-glass

I am working on an application that makes use of direction, and needs to be able to understand N/S/E/W, or in degrees off of north.  I was curious how we can do that?  I didnt really see a compass built into the device as much as a sample app.  Does that mean that i am going to need to remake the compass with the accelerometers, etc or is there a built in utility?

Comment: yea, thats what i was thinking:  `LocationManager` and `Criteria` to get information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A demonstration compass app is one of the applications available from Google at https://developers.google.com/glass/samples/gdk

Comment: Thats what i was starting to think.  Use `LocationManager` with `Criteria` in the example located at: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/location-sensors

Answer (score 0):

Google has provided various demonstration applications. A Compass application is one of those. They have published these applications with "open source" licenses (though you should read it yourself and follow its conditions"). Here is an excerpt from the compass demonstration application

> > 1. Grant of Copyright License.
>
> Subject to the terms and conditions of this License, each Contributor
>   hereby grants to You a perpetual, worldwide, non-exclusive, no-charge,
>   royalty-free, irrevocable copyright license to reproduce, prepare
>   Derivative Works of, publicly display, publicly perform, sublicense,
>   and distribute the Work and such Derivative Works in Source or Object
>   form.

Read the [full license agreement here][1]